# How to get specific data if the date is on weekend?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a timesheet where I can calculate the normal hours, overtime and weekend hours.

Here is the sheet I'm working on:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S4l2txvsjLQnWC4O5D3C0wj5kJWoeocNP7y4f2YOLcg/edit?usp=sharing

So far I managed to get the list of dates calculate hours worked and which is overtime, but what I can't figure out is how to calculate the worked hours on weekends, because I have 3 rates to pay (for normal hours, overtime and work on weekends).

I could to that if I put like a check box next to each date and manually select the weekends, but I wonder if I could do it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WEEKDAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985) to find weekends. With default settings, it returns one for Sunday and seven for Saturday.
Further using IF and OR you can process the data as you need.
This formula calculates the number of hours worked:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A11)=7,WEEKDAY(A11)=1),D11,0)
```

[image]

Comment: First, thank you very much for the answer it helped me a lot, but i need just a small help with this answer, the formula is great but how can i make it that if A11 is empty then the cell with this formula to be blank as well. On Hours and Overtime i used the IFS function like `=IFS(A11="", "", G11>0,0, G11=0, MAX(D11-8,0))` but not sure how to use this on your formula

Comment: I am glad to help.
`=IF(A11="", "", IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A11)=7,WEEKDAY(A11)=1),D11,0))`